# Navigation bar in IE6 and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, css-float

My navigation bar (right side) isn't working properly in IE6 and IE7...

Here is correct style of navigation bar (modern browsers):
[image: no issue]

Internet Explorer 6 (images on right side are under each other):
[image: images on right side are under each other]

Internet Explorer 7 (two images are missing on right side):
[image: two images are missing]

Here is source code of my navigation bar...

CSS:

```
/*----- NAV -----*/
#nav            { min-width: 920px; padding: 0 30px; background-color: #e9e9e9; }
#nav2           { width: 920px; height: 75px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; } 

/*----- LEFT -----*/
ul#topnav           { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; float: left; width: 650px; }
ul#topnav li            { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul#topnav a         { float: left; display: inline; height: 75px; background-position: left top; }
ul#topnav a:hover       { background-position: left -75px; }
ul#topnav a span        { display: none; }

/*----- RIGHT -----*/
ul#topnav2          { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; float: right; width: 270px; }
ul#topnav2 li           { float: right; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul#topnav2 a            { float: right; display: inline; height: 75px; background-position: left top; }
ul#topnav2 a:hover      { background-position: left -75px; }
ul#topnav2 a span       { display: none; }

/*----- IMAGES -----*/
ul#topnav li.ads a      { background-image: url(../images/ads.png); width: 60px; }
ul#topnav li.reg a      { background-image: url(../images/reg.png); width: 60px; }
ul#topnav li.login a        { background-image: url(../images/account.png); width: 60px; }
ul#topnav2 li.help a        { background-image: url(../images/help.png); width: 50px; }
ul#topnav2 li.terms a       { background-image: url(../images/terms.png); width: 50px; }
ul#topnav2 li.contact a     { background-image: url(../images/contact.png); width: 50px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav"><div id="nav2"> 

<ul id='topnav'>
    <li class='ads' title='Ads'><a href='ads.php'><span>Ads</span></a></li>
        <li><img src='images/spacer.png' alt='' /></li>
    <li class='reg' title='Register'><a href='register.php'><span>Register</span></a></li>
    <li class='login' title='Login'><a href='login.php'><span>Login</span></a></li>
</ul>
<ul id='topnav2'>
    <li class='contact' title='Contact'><a href='contact.php'><span>Contact</span></a></li> 
        <li><img src='images/spacer.png' alt='' /></li> 
    <li class='help' title='Help'><a href='help.php'><span>Help</span></a></li>
    <li class='terms' title='Terms'><a href='terms.php'><span>Terms</span></a></li>
</ul>

</div></div>
```

How can I fix this issue please?

Comment: Why would one want to fix that for these two browsers? The browsers are broken and crap. Period.

Comment: You should redirect IE6/7 users to a landing page where they can download a new browser. It is better that way for the web developer community.

Comment: Because still we can find people which are using this "browsers" and because I'm not sure if my source code is correct also for modern browsers.